# Running AJAX locally without a webserver

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have been looking for an answer for this for a month now. I am trying ro run the below script locally and getting "Access Denied" error.

Browser: IE 8
Environment: Locally, Intranet

Kindly share your thoughts on this. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GSDAssist</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Dynamic Ajax Content- � Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e){
            try{
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    }
    else return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }
    page_request.open('GET', url, true)
    page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
        document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
    if (!document.getElementById)
        return
    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var file=arguments[i]
        var fileref=""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
            if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
                fileref=document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
            }
            else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
                fileref=document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
            }
        }
        if (fileref!=""){
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
            loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
    }
}

</script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>GSDAssist</title>
</head>

<body style>

<div id="headerBar">
<marquee id="newsTicker" behavior="scroll" direction="left"><h4>Process Updates: Tickets trashed has to be moved to DBSP RECYCLE TICKET Assignment group</h4></marquee>
</div>

<div id="main">


<div style="width:300px; height:80px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:10px; float:left;">
    <img style="padding:5px; float:left;" src="img/logo.png" width="60" />
    <h2 style="float:left; margin-left:5px;">GSDAssist</h2>
</div>

<div style="clear:both; float:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">

<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('01/1.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">#</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('a/a.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">A</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('b/b.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">B</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('c.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">C</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('d.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">D</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('e.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">E</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('f.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">F</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('g.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">G</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('h.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">H</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('i.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">I</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('j.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">J</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('k.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">K</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('l.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">L</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('m.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">M</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('n.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">N</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('o.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">O</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('p.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">P</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('q.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">Q</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('r.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">R</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('s.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">S</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('t.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">T</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('u.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">U</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('v.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">V</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('w.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">W</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('x.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">X</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('y.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">Y</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('z.html', 'contentarea');" class="btn">Z</a>

<br>
<br>
</div>
<div id="contentarea" style="clear:both; float:left;"><h3>Welcome to GSDAssist,</h3><p><h3>Choose the starting letter of the application to get started!</h3></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you dont use a JS-Lib? You dont need to implement Ajax manually. Use jQuery as example.

Comment: It seems your app is going to be strongly dependent on Microsoft technologies and 5 years old IE8 (and will not work anywhere else). Is that your intent? If not, you better say what you want to do instead of posting some random code.

Comment: browser security restrictions will stop js in pages running on your local filesystem from loading content via ajax

Comment: 1) Install Dropbox, 2) Put files in *Public* folder, 3) Right-click HTML file and select *Dropbox -> Get Public Link*, 4) Go to link

Comment: Looks like this complex `loadobjs()` function can be safely removed since it's never invoked, UNLESS the ajax is supposed to load content that includes a javascript call to 'loadobjs()`

Comment: in an intranet, why will you want `ajax`? just load the files from the html itself... ajax serves mainly as a way to request less information from a server to make the call faster ... in an intranet, speed will never be a problem

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input! I am very grateful. Ivan - What I want is to load HTML pages into the main page without the main page refreshing. I am avoiding iframes. This will be run Locally. Thanks again for all your valuable suggestions Guys. I am very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Balexandre, Your are very correct. Speed is not at all going to be a problem. But I want to load HTML pages into a main HTML page. I am avoiding IFrames. Ajax seemed to be the only way. Is there anyother way with which I can achieve the same ??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on this are that it's not going to work.

XHR calls are subject to same-domain security policies (CORS is an exception, but that's almost impossible to do without controlling the server, anyway, which requires a server, which is your problem to begin with).

The point is that browsers have set security policies in place, which mean that you must request XHR data from the ***same domain*** as your browser is currently on.

`file:///` is a completely different protocol than `http://`, and even so, browser security prevents an HTML page which is served locally from accessing `file://` content in an async fashion (to prevent a page from accessing all content on your hard drive, and sending all of your data anywhere in the world).

Just about every web-centric programming language at this point has a quick-start server included (except NodeJS, but writing a simple server in Node is also very easy).

The trick would be to set a server up that's available on your intranet, without modifying the domain.

Comment: Thanks for your input Norguard, if this is not gonna work can you suggest any other way out where I can load HTML pages without the main page refreshing ? Thanks!